# Attachments doesn't update

Tags: php, attachments

I did use wp_attachments to display images from posts by url. With that in functions.php

```
'function twentythirteen_the_attached_image() {
$post                = get_post();
$attachment_size     = apply_filters( 'twentythirteen_attachment_size', array( 724, 724 ) );
$next_attachment_url = wp_get_attachment_url();

/**
 * Grab the IDs of all the image attachments in a gallery so we can get the URL
 * of the next adjacent image in a gallery, or the first image (if we're
 * looking at the last image in a gallery), or, in a gallery of one, just the
 * link to that image file.
 */
$attachment_ids = get_posts( array(
    'post_parent'    => $post->post_parent,
    'fields'         => 'ids',
    'numberposts'    => -1,
    'post_status'    => 'inherit',
    'post_type'      => 'attachment',
    'post_mime_type' => 'image',
    'order'          => 'ASC',
    'orderby'        => 'menu_order ID'
) );

// If there is more than 1 attachment in a gallery...
if ( count( $attachment_ids ) > 1 ) {
    foreach ( $attachment_ids as $attachment_id ) {
        if ( $attachment_id == $post->ID ) {
            $next_id = current( $attachment_ids );
            break;
        }
    }

    // get the URL of the next image attachment...
    if ( $next_id )
        $next_attachment_url = get_attachment_link( $next_id );

    // or get the URL of the first image attachment.
    else
        $next_attachment_url = get_attachment_link( array_shift( $attachment_ids ) );
}

printf( '<a href="%1$s" title="%2$s" rel="attachment">%3$s</a>',
    esc_url( $next_attachment_url ),
    the_title_attribute( array( 'echo' => false ) ),
    wp_get_attachment_image( $post->ID, $attachment_size )
);
 }
endif;
```

Then I use code below to display attachments in the content

```
   <?php $args = array(
   'post_type' => 'attachment',
   'numberposts' => -1,
    'post_status' => null,
    'post_parent' => $post->ID,
   'post_mime_type' => 'image'
  );

   $attachments = get_posts( $args );

   if ( $attachments ) {
   $attachments = array_reverse( $attachments );
   $i = 0; 
   foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) : ?>
  <p class="<?php if($i==0) echo hidden_image ;?>">   

<?php echo wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment->ID, 'full' ); ?>

</p>
  <?php $i++ ;?>  
<?php        endforeach;    

 }
 ?>
```

It works fine, however after any post edition, like deleting images, trying to change posiitions It has no effect at all. When I remove image from post, It is still being displayed in post on website.  What did I do wrong, or what should I add to this. Is It related with database upadates or something? Any help would be cool ;)

Comment: Do you have any caching plugin in use?

Comment: I dont use any plugins on this website